# What's the $unwind,$project operator in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql, aggregation-framework

[image]

I want to get syllabus Id and country code according to the grade id(Input value is grade Id) using mongo db aggregation($project,$unwind,$match).

Comment: Is there something in the provided answer that you believe does not address your question? If so then please comment on the answer to clarify what exactly needs to be addressed that has not. If it does in fact answer the question you asked then please note to [Accept your Answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to the questions you ask

Answer (score 1):

You can try,

- `$match` main document of grade id,
- `$project` to show required fields and syllabuses id, `$reduce` to iterate loop of `syllabuses` array and `$cond` to check grade id in grades array then return `syllabusesId`

```
let gradeId = 1;
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $match: { "syllabuses.grades._id": gradeId } },
  {
    $project: {
      countryCode: 1,
      syllabusesId: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$syllabuses",
          initialValue: "",
          in: {
            $cond: [{ $in: [gradeId, "$$this.grades._id"] }, "$$this._id", "$$value"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Uiq-9TI0XNj)